# Mocha js tests not showing diff when strings not equal

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a simple unit test to assert a string is correct but it only shows me the test name that failed, not the diff of expected and actual results. For example, here is some silly test code:

```
describe('stackoverflow', function(){
    it('should be simple', function() {
        var someValue = 'A' + 1 + 2;
        assert.equal('A3', someValue);
    });
});
```

The the output isn't very helpful:

```
$ mocha

  stackoverflow
    1) should be simple   <--- this line is red
```

Yes I can see which test failed but I can't easily see why. I'd like to see something like:

```
$ mocha

  stackoverflow
    1) should be simple

       Expected: 'A3'
       Actual  : 'A12'
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you are reporting, whether I use Node's own assert or Chai's assert. In either case, I get an `AsssertionError` that shows the expected and actual values (not exactly in the same format you show, but still, they are there).

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had another test afterwards that had no timeout set (because it is very slow) and uses the async pattern but I wasn't calling `done()`

Here is test.js that demonstrates the problem I was seeing (I've deleted all unnecessary junk):

```
var assert = require("assert");

describe('basic', function(){
    it('should be simple', function() {
        var someValue = 'A' + 1 + 2;
        assert.equal('A3', someValue);
    });
});

describe('slow', function(){
    it('should not explode', function(done) {
        this.timeout(0); // because it takes ages
    });
});
```

The solution was simply to make sure I call done() in the async test:

```
var assert = require("assert");

describe('basic', function(){
    it('should be simple', function() {
        var someValue = 'A' + 1 + 2;
        assert.equal('A3', someValue);
    });
});

describe('slow', function(){
    it('should not explode', function(done) {
        this.timeout(0); // because it takes ages
        done();
    });
});
```